# Query an existing socket's address family in Python

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm passing a socket file descriptor using a UNIX domain socket to a Python 3 program. I would like to query the socket and determine its address family.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513333/46192) the `getsockname` system call is used to achieve the same result in C. However, Python's `socket.getsockname` function doesn't return the address family, instead assuming the caller already knows it. Furthermore, it only works on sockets, not on file descriptors, and creating a socket object from a file descriptor requires passing the address family as well.

Is there a way to query the address family from Python?

EDIT: I want to emphasize that I am looking for the address family of an already open socket, for which I have the file descriptor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just pass the file descriptor to `socket.socket`, giving it as the `fileno=` keyword attribute. The socket class figures out the type of socket corresponding to the file descriptor. You can then find the family as @klaus suggested: with `s.family`.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
print("original socket", s)
desc = s.fileno()
print("file descriptor", type(desc), desc)
new_s = socket.socket(fileno=desc)
print("new socket", new_s.family, int(new_s.family))
```

Here I'm creating a socket in python, but then extracting the file descriptor from the socket object (producing an ordinary `int` containing the descriptor number) so as to demonstrate putting it back into a new socket object. Running the above produces:

```
original socket <socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 0)>
file descriptor <class 'int'> 3
new socket AddressFamily.AF_INET 2
```

**EDIT**
Hmm... the above method does not seem to work with `AF_INET6` sockets, at least in my python 3.5.2 version.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
new_s = socket.socket(fileno=s.fileno())
print(new_s)
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('::%1', 0, 0, 1)>
```

That seems like a clear bug to me. The documentation says:

> If fileno is specified, the values for family, type, and proto are auto-detected from the specified file descriptor.

You may need to examine `new_s.laddr` and heuristically determine the family. (For `AF_INET6`, `laddr` will be a 4-tuple, whereas `AF_INET` uses a 2-tuple). If you expect `AF_UNIX` or other families, you might need to extend that.

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed this part of the documentation. I see there is an open ticket about this: https://bugs.python.org/issue28134, although I checked Python 3.7 on Linux and it worked there.

Answer (score 1):

You can query a socket's address family in python checking the .family attribute. There are other attributes saved in the sock object also

```
import socket
import sys
# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.create_connection(('www.stackoverflow.com', 80))
print(sock)
print(sock.family)
```

The output is

```
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('x.x.x.x', y), raddr=('x.x.x.x', 80)>
AddressFamily.AF_INET
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote palivek, I want to find the address family of an existing socket, for which I have an open file descriptor, not to translate an address to find the selected address family.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want information about the socket, I would suggest `socket.getaddrinfo`.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo):

> The function returns a list of 5-tuples with the following structure:
>
> (family, type, proto, canonname, sockaddr)

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("example.org", 80, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET6: 10>, <SocketType.SOCK_STREAM: 1>,
 6, '', ('2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946', 80, 0, 0)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketType.SOCK_STREAM: 1>,
 6, '', ('93.184.216.34', 80))]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to find the address family of an existing socket, for which I have an open file descriptor, not to translate an address.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on ctypes I wrote so I could use older versions of Python:

```
import os
import socket
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL('libc.so.6', use_errno=True)
libc.getsockname.argtypes = [c_int, c_void_p, POINTER(c_int32)]
libc.getsockopt.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, c_int, c_void_p, POINTER(c_int32)]

def get_sock_family(fd):
    family = c_ushort(0)
    length = c_int32(sizeof(family))
    ret = libc.getsockname(fd, byref(family), length)
    if ret:
        errno = get_errno()
        raise OSError(errno, os.strerror(errno))

    return socket.AddressFamily(family.value)

def get_sock_type(fd):
    socket_type = c_int()
    length = c_int32(sizeof(socket_type))
    ret = libc.getsockopt(fd, socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_TYPE, byref(socket_type), length)
    if ret:
        errno = get_errno()
        raise OSError(errno, os.strerror(errno))

    return socket.SocketKind(socket_type.value)
```