# Get socket domain from descriptor

Tags: c++, sockets, ipv6, ipv4

I have a socket descriptor `descriptor`, which has been initialized by either of the following:
 - `int descriptor = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`
 - `int descriptor = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`

But I don't know which of the two. I would like to determine whether the socket corresponding to `descriptor` is an IPv4 or an IPv6 socket. I know that, for example, one can use `getsockopt` to determine the socket type (e.g., `SOCK_STREAM` vs `SOCK_DGRAM`) but I cannot seem to find a way to determine the socket domain (e.g., `PF_INET` vs `PF_INET6`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(How) Can I determine the socket family from the socket file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513298/how-can-i-determine-the-socket-family-from-the-socket-file-descriptor)

Comment: What is your platform? In linux, you can do `getsockopt(SO_DOMAIN)`. See `man 7 socket` for details.

Comment: Thank you! I’m interested in Linux and OSX.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Get address family from socket. Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331610/get-address-family-from-socket-linux)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get address family from socket. Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331610/get-address-family-from-socket-linux)